# Java - Advancing Characters in a String

Tags: java, parsing, substring

I have some String that I'm analyzing to find if it exists in a specific grammar, and I'm getting stuck when checking terminals in the String.

I'd like to, once I've identified that the character in the String exists in the grammar, reset the target string to a substring of itself, albeit the character I just analyzed. So...

```
if(target.charAt(0) is in grammar)
   target = target.substring(/* target - 'a' */)
```

Comment: All the characters before or after the specified character?

Comment: Isn't it just `target = target.substring(1)` you're looking for?

Comment: It's all the characters after the specified character.

Comment: A string might not be the best type to use in your situation. A char array might be better. Best would probably be a char list, but since in Java you can only put the Character wrapper in lists and the wrapper is a bit cumbersome to work with, char array might serve you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.indexOf()` should do the trick here, if I understood the question correctly:

```
int index = str.indexOf(someChar);
if (index != -1) {
    str = str.substring(index);
}
```